# Crontab execute every 15 minutes for two days

Tags: unix, cron

After reading crontab manual I used the following command to execute my process for every 15 minutes from 18:00 to 23:00 of a day.

```
MIN      Minute field    0 to 59
HOUR     Hour field      0 to 23
DOM      Day of Month    1-31
MON      Month field     1-12
DOW      Day Of Week     0-6
CMD      Command         Any command to be executed.
```

My command,

```
*/15 18-23 * * * myexec
```

I want to run my process from the time `18:00` of the day to early morning `01:30` of next day. I want to run this each and every day. How do I do this?

Second Question, If I run this the above process only for weekdays, Is my following command is right?

```
*/15 18-23 * * 1-5 myexec
```

Comment: You want the executable to start running at 18:00 and die/stop at 1:30 in the night?

Comment: @Newbyte: yes. I want to stop. And again it should start at 18:00 of the day.

Comment: I think what you'll need to do is have one cronjob that starts it at 18:00, and one that kills it at 01:30 in the morning. Does that sound right?

Comment: @NewByte: Yes. It should end at 1.30 Morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need three cron records to run it till 1:30:

```
*/15 18-23 * * * myexec
*/15 0 * * * myexec
0,15 1 * * * myexec
```

The first two lines can be combines like this:

```
*/15 0,18,19,20,21,22,23 * * * myexec
```

If you need to run it only during weekdays think about those runs from midnight. If you want to follow the cycle you will need to run one of them in Saturday. And the command will be:

```
*/15 18-23 * * 1-5 myexec
*/15 0 * * 2-6 myexec
0,15 1 * * 2-6 myexec
```

**NB!** If you want to run it every 30 minutes (as per headline) you need to change your cron records on this way

```
*/30 18-23 * * 1-5 myexec
*/30 0 * * 2-6 myexec
0 1 * * 2-6 myexec
```